# Problem while performing insertion sort while simultaneously adding values

Tags: python, sorting

I made a program to take elements from a list and a tuple simultaneously {ie. one from list then from tuple and then back from list and so on} and placing them in a new list and sorting them while inserting using insertion sort. The problem I am facing is the numbers are not sorting properly.

the output I'm getting [8, 6, 9, 4, 3, 1, 2, 5, 7]
the output I want. [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

```
list = [8,6,4,2]
tuple = (9,5,7,1,3)

final = [list[0],] # creating a final list with the value list[0]
list.pop(0) # removing the first element from list

l = len(list)
t = len(tuple)

# now comparing whoes length is greater and assigning it to j
if l > t:
    j = l
else: 
    j = t

b = 0 # variable to keep the count of elements in the final list starting from 0 to n-1

for i in range(j):
    n = b
    
    if i < l: # Making sure the index dosen't exceed the list
        temp = list[i]
        final.append(temp) # appending the value to last
        while temp < final[n] & n>-1: 
            final[n+1] = final[n]
            n = n-1
        final[n+1] = temp
        b+=1 # a value is added to final list so the total no of elements increases
    
    n=b
    if i < t: # Making sure the index dosen't exceed the tuple
        temp = tuple[i]
        final.append(temp)
        while temp < final[n] & n>-1:
            final[n+1] = final[n]
            n = n-1
        final[n+1] = temp
        b+=1
print(final)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the `.sort()` method to get the correct order.

```
        ...
        b+=1
final.sort()
print(final)
```

Comment: I am not allowed to use sort function